# How do I change the phone number for incoming calls to international format on the mobile

Tags: samsung, international-prefix

My contacts have their phone number in the international format.  It needs to be this way, otheriwse I can't call them from another country.  As an example

```
+64 21 1234567
```

But the incoming calls have the local number, so the software can not correlate them with the contacts.  That is, I can't tell who is calling.  Example

```
021 1234567
```

Points to note (all phone models are Samsung)

1. On my previous phone, S6, things worked just fine as they did on S4 before 
   that.
2. Now that I have migrated to S7, I have the above problem (with the same contacts that were migrated across).
3. My wife had this issue with her S5 and I managed to fix with some setting.
4. My wife migrated to Note 5 and all still works fine for her.
5. I have gone through all the settings I can think of, several times but have not found any that will fix this.
6. I can fix it by adding the local number to the contact as well the international format.  WIth several hundred contacts, this is a lot of work and will still give problems when I am outside the country.
7. The SMS system works fine, its just the voice calls.
8. I am still with the same provider.

Where is the setting to fix this ?

Comment: Exactly that's working on all devices I've seen (still have to see the S7). Phone number identification usually bases on the last N digits only (with N ~ 8 AFAIK), exactly for these reasons. I'm not aware of any related setting, or where one might "adjust N".

Comment: As far as I know there is no settings for that on your side. The Caller-ID comes from your provider and you cannot change its format.